# Android application is developed with API 16. Can we use Appium for automating this App

Tags: android, appium

Our Android application is developed using API 16 (Android version 4.1). Will appium support automating this application on android devices with version >= 4.2.

As per Appium site. Appium supports API >=17. So my question is does it refer to the API used for developing the application or is it refer to device on which the application is installed and used for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the device max supported API version in your code and use Appium for devices with API > 16.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `As per Appium site. Appium supports API >=17.`?? Appium official site `appium.io` (**First page!!**) states clearly following:

```
Requirements:

iOS
Mac OSX 10.7+
XCode 4.5+ w/ Command Line Tools

Android
Mac OSX 10.7+ or Windows 7+ or Linux
Android SDK ≥ 16 (SDK < 16 in Selendroid mode)
```